# Finding Cassandra ssttable path programmatically

Tags: cassandra

During the course of dropping and recreating tables in Cassandra 3.0.9 I've noticed that Cassandra doesn't remove the corresponding data directories on disk.

I have a 2 part question:

Is there an established method for dropping a table and removing the corresponding directory in a single operation?

If not, is there a way to query Cassandra to find out the physical location of a table so it can be cleaned up afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that data is not deleted ? or are you talking about snapshot ?

Because every time you drop a table cassandra takes a snapshot of the data.

this is from the documentation

> Dropping a table triggers an automatic snapshot, which backs up the data only, not the schema.

You can read about it here : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/drop_table_r.html

there is a way to delete snapshots.

> nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 clearsnapshot

Documentation : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_delete_snapshot_t.html